# Replace Object Fields

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

PetForm

```
{
name:"Bobo",
type:"Golden Retriever",
food:null,
toys:null,
....
}
```

I want to replace the fields with the values of null to an empty string like this:

Result:

```
{
name:"Bobo",
type:"Golden Retriever",
food:"",
toys:"",
....
}
```

I did the following:

```
Object.keys(PetForm).forEach((key) => (PetForm[key] === null) && PetForm[key] == "");
```

Am I missing something in this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var petForm = {
  name: "Bobo",
  type: "Golden Retriever",
  food: null,
  toys: null
}
Object.keys(petForm).forEach(function(item) {
  if (petForm[item] === null) {

    petForm[item] = "";
  }

})

console.log(petForm)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to assign the value in the `&&` operator, you need just one equals sign: `PetForm[key] = ""`

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer through a quick code snippet. It really helps!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to keep the petform map and return a new object, you can use reduce function.

```js
var petform = {
  name:"Bobo",
  type:"Golden Retriever",
  food:null,
  toys:null,
}

var res = Object.keys(petform).reduce((acc, curr) => { acc[curr] = petform[curr] ? petform[curr] : '' ; return acc; }, {});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
name:"Bobo",
type:"Golden Retriever",
food:null,
toys:null
};

for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    (obj[key] === null) && (obj[key] = '');
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```